# How to differentiate $f(w) = \sum\left[(w.\Omega w)^2\right]-\sum\left[w.\Omega w\right]^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have a function $$f(w) = \sum\left[(w.\Omega w)^2\right]-\sum\left[w.\Omega w\right]^2$$
where $.$ indicates element wise multiplication, $w$ is a vector, $\Omega$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix.

I need to optimize the above function w.r.t $w$. The size of my problem is small enough to do this with any old non linear optimizer, but I was curious to know what the gradient looks like, should I ever want to feed it in to the optimizer.

So this became a little toy puzzle for me to play with whilst alone in the office, but my persistent failure at finding the answer has become annoying.

In attempting to solve this, I noted that at some point I would need to find
$$\frac{\partial (w.\Omega w)}{\partial w}$$

I'm pretty sure I have correctly worked out that this is
$$w.\Omega + diag(\Omega w)$$
where $diag(x)$ converts the vector $x$ into a diagonal matrix.

To verify this, I have the following Matlab code. I can translate to R if required for this question.

```
a = randn(100000,1);
b = a + randn(100000,1);
c = a - b + randn(100000,1);
omega = cov([a b c], 1);
w = [0.1 0.5 0.4];

r = w'.*omega*w';
drdw = omega.*w' + diag(omega*w');
d = 0.000000001;
i = 3;
w_ = w;
w_(i) = w_(i) + d;
r_ = w_'.*omega*w_';
disp((r_ - r) ./ d)
disp(drdw(:,i))
```

So with that result in my pocket, I focused on the first term of $f$. My reasoning is as follows

$$\frac{\partial \sum\left[(w.\Omega w)^2\right]}{\partial w} = \sum\left[\frac{\partial ((w.\Omega w)^2)}{\partial w}\right]$$
application of chain rule gives
$$2.\sum\left[(w.\Omega w) \frac{\partial (w.\Omega w)}{\partial w}\right]$$
and we already have the pocket solution from earlier.

But now when I try to verify this solution, it goes wrong.

```
r = sum(w'.*omega*w');
i = 3;
drdw = sum((w'.*(omega*w')).*(omega.*w' + diag(omega*w'))) * 2;
d = 0.000000001;
w_ = w;
w_(i) = w_(i) + d;
r_ = sum(w_'.*omega*w_');
disp((r_ - r) ./ d)
disp(drdw(i))
```

But where does it go wrong?

**EDIT**

As noted by Abdullah, there was a bug in my code, rather than a flaw in my maths. Correct code is

```
r = sum((w'.*omega*w').^2);
i = 3;
drdw = sum((w'.*(omega*w')).*(omega.*w' + diag(omega*w'))) * 2;
d = 0.000000001;
w_ = w;
w_(i) = w_(i) + d;
r_ = sum((w_'.*omega*w_').^2);
disp((r_ - r) ./ d)
disp(drdw(i))
```

Comment: Please use `\sum` for whatever your sum thing is in the LaTeX print.

Comment: @SeanRoberson done.

Comment: What are you denoting with the brackets?

Comment: @DuncanW if you mean the $[...]$, this encloses everything that is in scope of the $\Sigma$ operator.

Comment: I wish I knew enough MatLab (or R—I am a filthy Python-using physicist) to determine if I'm wholly off-base. But it looks to me that your "d" is of mismatched dimension to "w".

Comment: @DuncanW adding a scalar (`d`) to a vector (`w`) in Matlab just adds `d` to every element of `w`. Similarly `./` indicates element wise division.

Comment: Probably going to give up now from lack of code knowledge :P. The one thing I'd be careful of is strange interactions between the Hadamard product and the difference quotient approximation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have MATLAB installed on my personal laptop and it will take a while to download Octave, so the following is hypothetical, i.e. debugging on paper, sigh.

I think it goes wrong with how you use the sum function of MATLAB. Since you are not passing the sum direction and `(w'.*(omega*w')).*(omega.*w' + diag(omega*w'))` is a matrix, `sum` does the following according to the MATLAB reference documentation

> If A is a matrix, then sum(A) returns a row vector containing the sum
>   of each column.

Try `sum((w'.*(omega*w')).*(omega.*w' + diag(omega*w')),2)`.

Also `r_ = sum(w_'.*omega*w_');` seems fishy. `w_'.*omega*w_'` is a vector, so `sum` will return a scalar and `r_` is supposed to be a vector, too. But I don't know your application so I am not sure.

Edit: if $r = \sum [(w.\Omega w)^2]$ then `r = sum(w'.*omega*w');` is not the correct MATLAB code to implement it.

Comment: I think you might be on to something. Unfortunately I won't have time to verify this until later today. Naturally, I will let you know.

Comment: Any updates? I could not test it myself. I am not sure what you mean by squaring a vector. But I am curious.

Comment: The correct point in your answer was noting that I was missing the exponent. I will update the question with the answer. Incidentally, I am not squaring the vector, I am squaring the elements of the vector.

Comment: Awesome! I am happy that it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

Think I got a little epiphany, actually. Burning the midnight oil a bit, but oh well.

$dw$ is a shorthand, at least in our beloved application-speak, for "small variation in w." The core of the issue is that the code doesn't implement a proper defintition of "small variation" in a vector.

To linearly approximate $dw$, your code adds some small constant to each term in the $w$ vector. This addition does not accurately capture all degrees of freedom of $w$, as adding a fixed constant to all three elements only changes the magnitude of the vector. I'd imagine that taking the sum of $w$ and some vector with three small, independently-varying elements would give accurate results.

As to why the code happened to give accurate results for the first example but failed for the second, I'm not good for an answer.

Comment: There is some confusion here, started with me, and unfortunately spread to you :(. In our earlier discussion, I told you that `w + d` would add `d` to each element of `w`, which (on it's own) is correct. However,  my code actually says `w(i) + d`, which only adds `d` to the ith element of `w`. Sorry for my mistake in our earlier discussion. Don't stay up too late though. Get some rest, try again tomorrow. If you solve it after the bounty deadline, I will start another bounty and award it accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I'm finally giving up then :) Would be nice to have had some MatLab experience, as that seems to be the hang-up; I'll append it to a now-very-long list of languages to learn. Interesting problem, and good luck.